# Incompatible Types in assignment to data structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, struct, typedef

i received this error when i compile my project.

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Matrix4’ from type ‘double (*)[4]’
```

My struct is something like this:

```
typedef struct testtest {
    Matrix4 tMat;
} test;
```

with a global variable:

```
typedef double Matrix4[4][4];
```

Now, i'm assigning inside the program a parameter to the related parameter of the struct like this:

```
test *newNode;
newNode = (test *)malloc(sizeof(test));
Matrix4 transformMatrix;
//inizializing the matrix....
//...
newNode->tMat = transformMatrix;  //<----HERE is the ERROR
```

Also if I change the struct into this:

```
typedef struct testtest {
    double tMat[4][4];
} test;
```

i receive a similar error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double[4][4]’ from type ‘double (*)[4]’
```

Does anyone know where i'm wrong please? Thank you so much :-)

Comment: How about giving us the structure of `newNode`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with "typedef double Matrix4[4][4];"? typedef is used to define a new type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I couldn't copy the memory from a field that is not already created. The memcpy works but only if i use a different node, so the newNode is just used for temporary (allocating memory before for it with malloc).
So something like this:

```
test *newNode;
test *recur;
newNode = (test *)malloc(sizeof(test));
Matrix4 transformMatrix;
//inizializing the matrix....
//...
memcpy(recur->tMat, transformMatrix, sizeof(newNode->tMat));
```

This works. Thank you all to let me understand new things :-)

Answer (score 1):

Array name often decays to pointer to first element when it is a part of expression, except when an operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` operator.
`newNode->tMat` is of type `double[4][4]`. `transformMatrix`, when assigned to `newNode->tMat`, is converted to pointer to its first element, i.e of type `double (*)[4]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do:

1. Make `tMat` a pointer to `Matrix4`.

   ```
   typedef struct testtest {
       Matrix4 *tMat;
   } test;

   newNode->tMat = &transformMatrix;
   ```
2. Use `memcpy`.

   ```
   memcpy(newNode->tMat, transformMatrix, sizeof(newNode->tMat));
   ```

Comment: [edit] i didn't save the code and it shows me this error:   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memcpy_ssse3_rep () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-rep.S:579
579 ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-rep.S: No such file or directory.

Comment: I solved it, I couldn't copy the memory from a field that is not already created. The memcpy works but only if i use a different node, so the newNode is just used for temporary (allocating memory before for it with malloc). I write a response for it. Thank you anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

C treats array objects differently from everything else<sup>1</sup>, so you cannot assign the contents of one array to the other using the `=` operator; IOW

```
T src[N], dest[N];
...
dest = src;
```

won't work.

To copy the contents of one (non-string) array to another, use the `memcpy` library function:

```
memcpy( dest, src, sizeof dest );
```

For strings, use either the `strcpy` or `strncpy` functions.

```
strcpy( dest, src );
strncpy( dest, src, sizeof dest - 1 );
```

---

<sup>1. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.  The resulting expression is not a *modifiable lvalue*, and thus cannot be used as the target of an assignment.  Read [this essay](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html), especially the section labeled "Embryonic C", for some insight into why this is the case.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C are not [first-class data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen), and cannot appear on either side of an assignment.

You can assign a pointer to an array (a zero-copy reference - the data is not moved), and you can perform a byte-by-byte copy.  If the elements themselves are first-class types, you can also perform an element-by-element copy.

Structures are first-class types, so you can wrap an array in a struct and assign directly, so in your case:

```
test transformMatrix;
//inizializing the matrix....
//...
*newNode = transformMatrix;
```

would be valid.